# AngularJS - angularAnimate causes error: Cannot read property '' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, bower

I tried to delete the "bower-components" folder, and then run `bower install` to make sure this works.

After this, I was asked to choose the correct angular version:

[image]

First of all, I have no idea what version to choose, I tried choosing the newest version (Option 3 version: `angular#1.4.0`) but then I got this weird console error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined
    at lookup (angular-animate.js:617)
    at animationRunner (angular-animate.js:681)
    at performAnimation (angular-animate.js:1284)
    at angular-animate.js:959
    at angular-animate.js:539
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15606)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15824)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1628)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4426)
    at doBootstrap (angular.js:1626)
```

Does anyone know what causes this error?

Comment: You need ngAnimate and angular versions to be the same, so check it.

Comment: So choose option nr. 2? Then I get this error: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$cookieReaderProvider <- $$cookieReader <- $cookies <- $cookieStore <- authInterceptor <- $http <- Auth <- $cookies
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24cookieReaderProv…0%3C-%20authInterceptor%20%3C-%20%24http%20%3C-%20Auth%20%3C-%20%24cookies`

Comment: This is related to your injected modules, angular does not find the $cookies module.

Comment: I haven't used cookies so I don't know how to resolve the problem. Noobie, I know, but I've used the angular-fullstack generator from here: https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack

Comment: Just check if the file that loads this module is there.

Comment: Do you mean this?: `angular.module('welldanaJavascriptApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ui.router',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'ngAnimate',
  'cgNotify'
])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79065/discussion-between-detilium-and-jsisawesome).

Answer (score 3):

**I solved my problem quite easily**

The only thing I did was to simply change the `angular-cookies` to `1.3.15`

**So change this**:

```
"angular-cookies": "~1.4.0",
```

**To this**

```
"angular-cookies": "~1.3.15",
```

*I don't know whether this is a correct solution, but atleast it worked for me*

Comment: This is the right way to do it. They should be of the same version.